# group by/formatting json data in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, json, grouping

Sorry if this has been asked before. I have the JSON structure like:

```
{"data":[
   {"Date":"03/04/2016","Key":"A","Values":"123"},
   {"Date":"04/04/2016","Key":"A","Values":"456"},
   {"Date":"03/04/2016","Key":"B","Values":"789"},
   {"Date":"04/04/2016","Key":"B","Values":"012"}
]}
```

I want to change this to a different format which is basically grouped by Key and combines rest  of the field in Values

```
{"Result":[
   {
     "Key":"A"
     "Values":[["03/04/2016","123"], ["04/04/2016","456"]]
    },      
   {"Key":"B"
     "Values":[["03/04/2016","789"]},["04/04/2016","012"]]
     }
]}
```

I want to do this javascript/html

Comment: {"Key":"B"[ .... this structure is invalid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could iterate and build a new object if not exist.

```js
var object = { "data": [{ "Date": "03/04/2016", "Key": "A", "Values": "123" }, { "Date": "04/04/2016", "Key": "A", "Values": "456" }, { "Date": "03/04/2016", "Key": "B", "Values": "789" }, { "Date": "04/04/2016", "Key": "B", "Values": "012" }], result: [] };

object.data.forEach(function (a) {
    if (!this[a.Key]) {
        this[a.Key] = { Key: a.Key, Values: [] };
        object.result.push(this[a.Key]);
    }
    this[a.Key].Values.push([a.Date, a.Values]);
}, Object.create(null));

console.log(object);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this can be a better answer (but [Nina](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38082313/3078890)'s answer is the match for your problem terms) if items of data array have different properties and you don't want to change input data.

```js
var raw = {"data":[
   {"Date":"03/04/2016","Key":"A","Values":"123"},
   {"Date":"04/04/2016","Key":"A","Values":"456"},
   {"Date":"03/04/2016","Key":"B","Values":"789"},
   {"Date":"04/04/2016","Key":"B","Values":"012"}
]};

var result = new Map;
raw.data.forEach(entry => {
  var key = entry.Key;
  if (this[key])
    return this[key].push(getClonedData(entry));

  this[key] = [getClonedData(entry)];
  result.set(key, {
    Key: key,
    Values: this[key]
  })
}, Object.create(null));

var filtered = {
  result: [...result.values()]
}
console.log(filtered);

function getClonedData(entry) {
  data = Object.assign({}, entry);
  delete data.Key;
  return data;
}
```